# Reporting service with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Does SQL Server Express 2005 contains Reporting Service.
If yes I installed SQL SErver express 2005 edition but i am not able to see Reporting Service.

Help...

Advance services, doesnt helps..

Answer (score 8):

You need to install [SQL Server Express 2005 with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4C6BA9FD-319A-4887-BC75-3B02B5E48A40&displaylang=en).